# Display string from text file using array

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't understand what is wrong with my code, I trying display string from text file using array, but this don't display anything. In debug, cycle 7 time as expected, but not return the string that is in text file.

```
            const int iMovie = 7;
        string[] iFilm = new string[iMovie];
        int iNames;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
        {
            for (iNames = 0; iNames < iMovie; iNames++)
            {
                iFilm[iNames] = Convert.ToString(sr.Read());
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the program.");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ReadLine() if you want an entire line?

```
const int iMovie = 7;
string[] iFilm = new string[iMovie];
int iNames;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
{
    for (iNames = 0; iNames<iMovie && !sr.EndOfStream; iNames++)
    {
        iFilm[iNames] = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
foreach(String line in iFilm)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the program.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Console.WriteLine(iFilm[iNames]);

```
for (iNames = 0; iNames < iMovie; iNames++) {
      iFilm[iNames] = Convert.ToString(sr.Read());
      Console.WriteLine(iFilm[iNames]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing out the data stored in the array.

```
 Console.WriteLine(iFilm[iNames]);
```

Put the line above in the for loop like;

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
    {
      for (iNames = 0; iNames<iMovie && !sr.EndOfStream; iNames++)
      {
        iFilm[iNames] = sr.ReadLine(); 
        Console.WriteLine(iFilm[iNames]); //this line to print

      } 
    }
```